# Use Markdown code block in Telegram PHP API

Tags: php, html, markdown, telegram, telegram-bot

I want to send `code block` with telegram bot in PHP language.
I already use "`", but I did not get any result.

I use HTML parse_mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are 2 formatting options: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#formatting-options

also see parse_mode in sendMessage: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage

you should set it in this param and then use concurrent formatting (markdown in your case)

UPD if you use html mode, use `<code>` for inline block and `<pre>` for multiline

Comment: He can use `parse_mode = html` with `<pre>` tag to format code.

Comment: or <code> in case of inline block like "`" in the question